# pass data from masterViewController to other ViewController in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to pass a value to a property from one class to another.
In `LAClaimReportViewController`, I have a property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) LAClaimReport *claimReport;
```

I want to pass the value to claimReport property (of LAClaimReportViewController)from below code of masterViewController.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if ([record.submitted isEqualToNumber:@0] && record != _selectedReport)
    {
        [self.detailViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        LAClaimReportViewController *claimReportViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ClaimReportView"];
        [self.detailViewController.navigationController pushViewController:claimReportViewController animated:YES];
       //Question: i want to assign record to claimReport of LAClaimReportViewController. how to do that.
    }
}
```

Comment: After you create claimReportViewController: claimReportViewController. claimReport = yourClaimReport

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/366346

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@try this

[claimReportViewController setclaimReport:selectedReport];